# How to install PCSIM library?

Tags: python

How to install PCSIM library under Windows 7 ( http://www.lsm.tugraz.at/pcsim/ ). It is open source project!

Comment: Scroll to the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Blender Those instructions are for Linux, and won't work on windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to install a Linux distribution that has pcsim available in its packages on a second partition, or in a virtual machine (e.g. qemu or virtualbox).

As you can see [here](http://www.lsm.tugraz.at/pcsim/usermanual/html/node8.html), pcsim has a *lot* of dependencies (other software that it needs to build or work). All of those have to be installed before you can even try and compile pcsim. If you have never installed anything from source code on Windows, you're in for a challenge to put it mildly.

Installing Python itself is pretty easy, since there are Windows installer packages for it available.

Installing pure Python modules is generally not that difficult; unpack the source, open a command window, change to the package directory and typing `python setup.py install` will often do the trick.

But some Python modules and definitely some of the other dependencies require a C or C++ compiler and related utilities. I would reccomend you try installing [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/InstallationHOWTOforMinGW) (which also has Windows installers available) as a development environment. Hopefully the rest of the requirements (that don't have windows installers) can be compiled with this.